# Converting comma separated string using XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am passing string input parameter as below to XSLT,

passId=" Line1 | Line 2| Line3";

Accessing in XSLT as below :

```xml
<xsl:param name="passId"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head></head>
<xsl:value-of select="$passId"/>
<br/>
</html>
</xsl:template>
```

Expected output is in new line each:

Line1

Line2

Line3

How we achieve this output using XSLT template.

Actual input -- Line1 | Line 2| Line3";

Expected Output:

Line1

Line2

Line3

As above in XSLT all are printing in same line.

Comment: Please post the expected output **as code** (if your output is HTML, then show the exact HTML markup you want to get). Also state which version of XSLT your processor supports (see:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153).

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and also read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Xalan processor, you should be able to do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" extension-element-prefixes="str">

<xsl:param name="passId"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head/>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="str:split($passId, '|')">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
                <br/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With the parameter you are showing this will return:

```
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>Line1 <br> Line 2<br> Line3<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: y.arazim, I tried the step you mentioned above, But in sql db it shows below error while updating that template in column. Error as below.  "Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The data types varchar and varchar are incompatible in the '|' operator. "   Error from this line <xsl:for-each select="str:split($passId, '|')">

Comment: @KesavanBalakrishnan As I stated, this code is intended for the Xalan processor (which, AFAIK, is the default XSLT processor in Java). It should also work for any other processor that supports the str:split extension function. I don't know what "sql db" has to with XSLT processing at all. You were already asked to identify your XSLT processor, but you still haven't done so.